# How to use PDDestination class in PDFbox?

Tags: pdfbox

How to use `PDDestination` class in PDFbox ?
whether  `getPagenumber()` method will return the current page number

can any one share u r views 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The usage of `PDDestination` or `PDAction` is very similar to the one of `PdfDestination` or `PdfAction` of *iText*.

So you may want to search *iText* examples firstly.

Specifically on *PDFBox*,
e.g.
the following makes the first open page to page 5.

```java
PDDestination dest = new PDPageDestination();
// When you open this PDF, you will see page 5.
dest.setPageNumber(4)
PDActionGoTo action = new PDActionGoTo();
action.setDestination(dest);
document.getDocumentCatalog().setOpenAction(action);
```

Comment: You need to set the PDPage, not the page number.